# How to map collection with incrementing inner array (for loop)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

I am looking for an elegant solution to create the following collection. The final keys do not matter, but I need to iterate the `qty` amount in a for loop and then flat output the final result.

```php
$a = collect([
    ['id' => 1, 'qty' => 5, 'height' => 4],
    ['id' => 2, 'qty' => 5, 'height' => 2]
]);

/*
    [
        '1' => ['height' => 4],
        '2' => ['height' => 4],
        '3' => ['height' => 4],
        '4' => ['height' => 4],
        '5' => ['height' => 4],
        '6' => ['height' => 2],
        '7' => ['height' => 2],
        '8' => ['height' => 2],
        '9' => ['height' => 2],
        '10' => ['height' => 2],
    ]
*/
```

Ideas much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`map` with `times` could do the work. `collapse` is used to level two arrays into one. You may update `array_only` part to add new keys for the result.

```
return collect([['id' => 1, 'qty' => 5, 'height' => 4], ['id' => 2, 'qty' => 5, 'height' => 2]])
    ->map(function ($elt) {
        return Collection::times($elt['qty'], function ($number) use ($elt) {
            return array_only($elt, 'height');
        });
    })
    ->collapse()
    ->toArray();
```